# How to get JavaScript Object with mobx toJS

Tags: reactjs, mobx

My code:

```js
configure({
    enforceActions: 'always',
  })
  
  class Store {
    constructor() {
      makeAutoObservable(this)
    }
  
    model = observable.map({
      name: 'Alex',
    })
  }
  
  const store = new Store()
  
  const Demo = () => {
    console.log(toJS(store.model))
  }
```

result:   Map(1) {'name' => 'Alex'}
I don't want Map
How do I get one JavaScript Object ?

Comment: version:
mobx: 6.3.1

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the map to a regular JavaScript object by using `toJS`

```js
import { makeAutoObservable, observable, toJS } from 'mobx'

class Store {
  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this)
  }

  model = observable.map({
    name: 'Alex',
  })
}

const store = new Store()

const Demo = () => {
  const modelObject = Object.fromEntries(toJS(store.model))
  console.log(modelObject)
}

Demo()
```

In this code, the toJS() function is used directly on the myObservable object to convert it into a plain JavaScript object.

But as you don't want to map you can do this :

```js
import { observable, toJS } from 'mobx';

class Store {
  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this);
  }

  model = observable({
    name: 'Alex',
  });
}

const store = new Store();

const plainObject = toJS(store.model);

console.log(plainObject);
```

Comment: your first demo output is [['name'.'Alex']], not { name: 'Alex' } 

mobx version  6.x

Comment: Yeah you are right i have updated it